# how do i store an drag & drop item into cookies and then retrieve it in another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm currently working on a project that's somehow like a drag and drop customization thing. So it goes like this:

Step1: choose a cake
So the user will drag and drop the cake into a box. (that's done up already)

After dropping the cake in the box they can proceed to step 2.

Step2: Add your desired toppings

I somehow asked someone if there's anyway to read the cake that was dropped into the box and make it appear in the step2 page (another page) and i got an answer to use js cookies. But all the cookies tuts I read on usually stores username and etc. I'm not a person who scripts so i don't really know how to look up for exact answers on google. I'm really desperate (deadline coming) and all I can do is ask here.

Can someone kindly help me here? Your answers will be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cookies, use a `GET` or `POST` parameter. This is a 'funnel' or 'wizard', you shouldn't use cookies for that.

Look at it like this: what if someone opens two instances and tries two different cakes? Weird things will happen if you us cookies.

Comment: hello there, care to explain a little further what's a GET or POST parameter? Any tuts or anything? thanks!

Comment: These are basic things a web programmer should be aware of. Find a tutorial or do a class? I know you have a deadline coming up, but you need at least some programming skill.

Comment: I'm a web designer student and yes i'm studying in a web design class but all I learnt is htmls and not java so I'm really lost at this. And my deadline is tonight so I'm really very rush for it. Anyway thanks I'll find some other way @_@

Comment: and this get and post parameter is using PHP right? I'm trying to find something that don't requires PHP to do